# R for loop generating NA's after 1000 iterations

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have a simple for loop that I'm using to remove any rows from my dataframe that involve two variables sharing a similar string and when I run the loop it iterates 1000 times and then starts generating NA's which breaks my loop.

| expiration | quote_datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-26 | 2021-02-26 10:00:00 |
| 2021-02-26 | 2021-02-27 10:00:00 |

```
for(row in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(grepl(df$expiration[row], df$quote_datetime[row],fixed=TRUE) == TRUE){
    df = df[-row,]
  }
}
```

I'm getting the error message

> Error in if (grepl(df$expiration[row], df$quote_datetime[row],  :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Each time I run it it eliminates a few more rows until it runs out of anything else to eliminate and then it runs without error. Appreciate help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue arises because the original data 'df' gets subset `if` the condition is TRUE, i.e. it will be one row less for every `if` TRUE case.  It could be resolved if we copy of the data

```
df2 <- df
for(row in 1:nrow(df)){
   if(grepl(df$expiration[row], df$quote_datetime[row],fixed=TRUE)){
     df2 <- df2[-row,]
    }
   }
```

---

Also, `grepl` is vectorized only for the 'x' and not for the `pattern`  So, if we need to do a vectorization, may need to `paste` the `pattern` together

```
df <- df[!grepl(paste(df$expiration, collapse="|"), 
              df$quote_datetime, fixed = TRUE), ]
```

---

Or use a function that does the vectorization for both 'x' and 'pattern i.e. `str_detect`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   filter(!str_detect(quote_datetime, fixed(expiration))
```